# Little assistance of my count function please. Tried the answers on this topic but no success

Tags: php

```
$sql= ("SELECT COUNT (id) AS total FROM grade ");

$result=mysqli_query($dbConnection, $sql);


echo $result['total'];
```

Nothing is printing on the screen. Blank screen. Table has records.

Comment: You forgot to fetch after your query http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php

Answer (score 1):

you have a space between `count` and `(id)` this will cause the query to fail.

the exact error if you displayed them would be

```
#1630 - FUNCTION YOURDB.COUNT does not exist. Check the 'Function Name Parsing and Resolution' section in the Reference Manual
```

Comment: $sql= ("SELECT COUNT(id) AS total FROM books ");

if($result=mysqli_query($dbConnection, $sql)){
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {

    echo $row["total"];
}

/* free result set */
mysqli_free_result($result);
}